# How to Optimize CSS Delivery in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In google page speed test. it shows Should Fix:

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Your page has 3 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

http://www.url.com/wp-content/themes/news-pro/style.css

http://www.url.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A400%2C700%7CPathway+Gothic+One&ver=3.0.2

how to fix this without plugin

Comment: Basically PageSpeed want you to include css in footer.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic. There are too many an answers to this question and answer that addresses the full problem - including the side effects - will be too long for this medium and will most likely be specific to your case and of little use to others.